# Get a graph/data that shows (last 1 year) on code checkins

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to get a graph/data that shows (last 1 year) on code checkins from a git repo?

I would like to get data on the number of code commits and the size of LOC.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Display a complete log which start at the given data.

```bash
# print the log since given time, on a single line 
# with branch names and graph.
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --since=<date>
```

---

### For LOC (lines of code)

> ***`--numstat`***
> Similar to `--stat`, but shows **number of added and deleted lines** in decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more machine friendly. For binary files, outputs two - instead of saying 0 0.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!  is there something that would show the increase/decrease in LOC as well?