# Git: Show files which were not recently modified

Tags: git, git-log

In order to clean some git repo, I'd like to list all files which didn't receive any new commit for more than some period (let's tell one year for example).

I know how to list X most recently modified files, but not how to do the opposite :)

Thanks.

Comment: Since you know how to find the set of files you don't want, just get the list of all tracked files and remove the files that have been modified recently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking about this but I'm wondering if there is not a nice way to do it out of the box with git :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 1-liner to show the files that have **not** been altered in the last year:

```
git ls-files | grep -v "$(git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since='1 year ago' | sort | uniq)"
```

You could perhaps wrap this up in an alias to make it easier to invoke.

Comment: `zsh: argument list too long: grep`

Answer (score 0):

Write a script which loop over all your files, extract the modification date from the files and then print it.

It has nothing to do with GIt. :-)

---

If you want to use git command to do it you can't use the ***`ls-tree`*** command:

```
# loop over the files and print last modification date
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | while read filename; do
  echo "$(git log -1 --format="%ad" -- $filename) $filename"
done
```

---

> **`ls-tree`**
>
> List the contents of a tree object
> `--name-only` - print out only file names

The loop and print out form the log of the file the last modification date

Comment: In my case this does not work as the creation/modification dates were overwritten to the date when I downloaded the files. That's why I wanted to do it with commits dates as it is not overwritten.

Comment: Here is what you can do instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979874/get-a-graph-data-that-shows-last-1-year-on-code-checkins/35980125#35980125

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the `grep: Argument list too long` error, one must work via files:

```
$ git ls-files --full-name | sort > all.git
$ git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since='1 year ago' | sort | uniq > recent.git
$ comm -23 all.git recent.git
```

(`comm` is a linux only utility, hopefully there are similar utilities for other platforms)